# How do I extract the elements of xml column?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

How do I extract the elements to xml column?

```
<V>
  <r>
    <ID>alkj</ID>
    <Date>2013-01-02T00:00:00-02:00</Date>
    <Value>97429.91</Value>
  </r>
  <r>
    <ID>asdf</ID>
    <Date>2014-01-02T00:00:00-02:00</Date>
    <Value>90121.18</Value>
  </r>
<V>
```

need only what is inside the element v, the return needs to be:

```
<r>
    <ID>alkj</ID>
    <Date>2013-01-02T00:00:00-02:00</Date>
    <Value>97429.91</Value>
  </r>
  <r>
    <ID>asdf</ID>
    <Date>2014-01-02T00:00:00-02:00</Date>
    <Value>90121.18</Value>
</r>
```

but I can not use

```
select colunaxml.query('(/v/r)') from tabela
```

because `V` is not always `V`! but the internal elements are always r

thank for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT colunaxml.query('(/*/r)')
```

If you already know the parent element names will always be something like `<v>`, `<a>`, `<b>`, or `<c>`, the XPath will probably execute faster when you specify them:

```
SELECT colunaxml.query('(/(v | a | b | c)/r)')
```

Comment: I understand, but I can never know the parent element, so that "SELECT colunaxml.query ('(/*/ r)')" is the perfect solution! vc is genius! tks!!